# R gbm what's the basic tree classifer rpart or ctree, how to reproduce the trees in gbm results

Tags: r, tree, gbm

What is the basic tree classifier for package `gbm`, `rpart` or `ctree`?

Suppose we want to do a 2-class classification with the following data:

```
D = iris[iris$Species!='setosa', ]
D$Species = as.factor(as.character(D$Species))
D$label = as.numeric(D$Species) - 1
D$Species = NULL
head(D)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width label
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4     0
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5     0
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5     0
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3     0
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5     0
56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3     0
```

The following is the result from rpart with max depth fixed at 1:

```
fit1 = rpart(data = D, label~., control = rpart.control(maxdepth=1), method = 'class')
fit1

n= 100 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 100 50 0 (0.50000000 0.50000000)  
  2) Petal.Width< 1.75 54  5 0 (0.90740741 0.09259259) *
  3) Petal.Width>=1.75 46  1 1 (0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```

The splitting variable is Petal.Width at 1.75.

The following is the tree from `gbm` with `shrinkage` as 1:

```
fit = gbm(data=D, label ~., shrinkage = 1, n.trees = 1, train.fraction = 1)
pretty.gbm.tree(fit, i.tree = 1)
  SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight Prediction
0        2      5.050000        1         2           3       9.610323     50  -0.240000
1       -1     -1.612903       -1        -1          -1       0.000000     31  -1.612903
2       -1      2.000000       -1        -1          -1       0.000000     19   2.000000
3       -1     -0.240000       -1        -1          -1       0.000000     50  -0.240000
```

The tree splits the root node using the 3rd column(indexed from 0 so 2+1 is 3) Petal.Length at value 5.05.

If I remove option `train.fraction = 1` there will be some randomness in the fitted result. Is it automatically doing some bagging or CV?

So the big question is, how could we reproduce the very first tree in `gbm` result using `rpart`, `ctree` or others? And what shrinkage value should we use to get that?

---

Update:

The results are consistent if `bag.fraction = 1` is added.

But why changing `shrinkage` won't affect the result? It only affects the result from the 2nd tree?

And how can we generate the 2nd tree in `gbm` results using `rpart`?

```
fit = gbm(data=D, label ~., shrinkage = 1, n.trees = 2, train.fraction = 1,bag.fraction = 1)
pretty.gbm.tree(fit, i.tree = 1)
  SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight Prediction
0        3      1.750000        1         2           3        19.4847    100   0.000000
1       -1     -1.629630       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     54  -1.629630
2       -1      1.913043       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     46   1.913043
3       -1      0.000000       -1        -1          -1         0.0000    100   0.000000
pretty.gbm.tree(fit, i.tree = 2)
  SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight Prediction
0        2     4.9500000        1         2           3       2.368983    100  0.1792148
1       -1    -0.9785858       -1        -1          -1       0.000000     54 -0.9785858
2       -1     1.5383721       -1        -1          -1       0.000000     46  1.5383721
3       -1     0.1792148       -1        -1          -1       0.000000    100  0.1792148
```

If the target is continuous, I can do it by following the ideas here http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/

But how can we do it for categorical target variables?